# IntelliJ IDEA/Android Studio - dart plugin: Missing overrides created wrong! Is this a bug?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, intellij-idea, dart

When creating a dart file in IntelliJ IDEA with this content

```
abstract class A {
  foo(int foo);
  bar(String bar);
}

class B extends A {

}
```

, there are obviously two overrides missing in 'B'.

When using the 'Create 2 missing override(s)'-feature, I get this red cursor, used in the LiveTemplates, around the 'Str' in 'String'. This also changes the 'int' to 'Str'.

When changing the code slightly, it suddenly works as expected.

Did anyone encounter this issue, too?

Can anyone reproduce this issue?

Is this a problem with my settings?

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: **Create missing override** quick fix is powered by the Dart Analysis Server, a tool included in the Dart SDK. In this case, IDE behaves only as a text editor, it inserts the text that the server says to insert. I'd suggest reporting the issue to https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues

Comment: So you think this a bug in the dart sdk? I thought this might be a bug in the intellij plugin.

Comment: yes, it's a problem with Dart SDK

Comment: Thanks, I've created an issue.

Comment: A change has already been created:
https://dart-review.googlesource.com/c/sdk/+/152400